# gcc option std=gnu++17 vs std=c++17

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

I encountered a compilation error when using g++ (I tried versions 8 to 11) with `-std=gnu++17` but the same code can be compiled using the option `-std=c++17`.

```
#include <complex.h>
int main()
{
    int I=0;
    return I;
}
```

With the option `-std=gnu++17`, this leads to the following error:

```
error: invalid cast from type '__complex__ float' to type 'int'
    5 |     int I=0;
```

With the option `-std=c++17` it compiles without warnings and errors.

I know that in the `complex.h` header there is a macro definition `#define I _Complex_I`. And the gcc documentation says that the option `-std=gnu++17` adds the GNU dialect of the respective c++ standard. Still, I do not understand why this is causing a difference in the compilation of the above program.

Background:
I encountered this behavior when I started to use the cmake feature `cxx_std_17` which adds the flag `std=gnu++17` and led to various compilation errors because one thirdparty library uses the identifier `I` and another includes the header `complex.h`.

Comment: With `std=gnu++17` the identifier `I` is reserved for the library. Do not use `std=gnu++17`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard says: (C++17 C.6.1/3):

> The C++ headers `<ccomplex>` (D.4.1) and `<ctgmath>` (D.4.4), as well as their corresponding C headers
> `<complex.h>` and `<tgmath.h>`, do not contain any of the content from the C standard library and instead
> merely include other headers from the C++ standard library.

So C's complex.h is not included in C++, meaning in your code `I` should not be defined to anything.

GCC does include the C content as an extension when GNU extensions are allowed. See [PR 82417](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/gcc/patch/20171010112844.GA28974@redhat.com/):

> As an extension the C++ version of <complex.h> includes the C version,
> but that defines macros with non-reserved names that should not be
> defined in ISO C++. Only include the C header for non-strict modes, or
> for pre-C++11 (because C++98 doesn't mention <complex.h> at all).

Answer (score 4):

You can find out the difference yourself by simply getting the results from the preprocessor with different standard settings like the following:

```
 g++ -std=gnu++17 main.cpp -E > gnu
 g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -E > std
```

and `diff` the files.

The underlying reason is, that the file `/usr/include/complex.h` is only taken if `__STRICT_ANSI__` is NOT set. By using the gnu extensions this macro is not set. You can see the selection in the file `/usr/include/c++/11/complex.h`

The installation path of your header files may differ, but I believe you can match the given information to your library installation.

In general `I` should not be defined in C++ but is if gnu extensions are in use. The hint is: Don't use such extensions as they may make your code incompatible with other compilers.

And quite clear, your code will brake if `I` is defined as "something" and will result in anything which is not a valid variable name.

Comment: Also a very helpful answer, I am wondering then that cmake automatically choose `std=gnu++17` but that is of course a different question.